# Sort nodes in xml file

Tags: c++, pugixml

I'm using the pugixml library, and i try to add some content (nodes) with the `fillWeek()` function after sorting existing nodes in my xml file, but the problem is, when i call the `sort()` function, nothing happens, the `_weekNode` is not updated. Here is a minimal and reproducible example code :

```
#include <pugixml.hpp>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

pugi::xml_document _doc;
pugi::xml_node _rootNode;
pugi::xml_node _weekNode;

bool compareNodesByAttribute(const pugi::xml_node &node1, const pugi::xml_node &node2)
{
    return std::strcmp(node1.attribute("From").value(), node2.attribute("From").value()) < 0;
}

void sort()
{
    std::vector<pugi::xml_node> nodesToSort;

    for (pugi::xml_node node = _rootNode.first_child(); node; node = node.next_sibling())
    {
        nodesToSort.push_back(node);
    }

    std::sort(nodesToSort.begin(), nodesToSort.end(), compareNodesByAttribute);

    for (const pugi::xml_node& node : nodesToSort)
    {
        _rootNode.remove_child(node);
    }

    for (pugi::xml_node node : nodesToSort)
    {
        _rootNode.append_copy(node);
    }

}

void loadXML()
{
    pugi::xml_parse_result result = _doc.load_file("Test.xml");

    if (result.status != pugi::status_ok)
    {
        pugi::xml_node declNode = _doc.prepend_child(pugi::node_declaration);
        declNode.append_attribute("version") = "1.0";
        declNode.append_attribute("encoding") = "UTF-8";
        declNode.append_attribute("standalone") = "yes";

        _rootNode = _doc.append_child("Root");
    }

    _rootNode = _doc.child("Root");
}

void makeWeek(const std::string& from, const std::string& to)
{
    _weekNode = _rootNode.append_child("Week");
    _weekNode.append_attribute("From").set_value(from.c_str());
    _weekNode.append_attribute("To").set_value(to.c_str());
}

void fillWeek()
{
    auto activity = _weekNode.append_child("Activity");
    activity.append_attribute("Type").set_value("0");
}

int main()
{
    loadXML();

    makeWeek("15/10","19/10");
    makeWeek("08/10","12/10");

    sort();

    fillWeek();

    _doc.save_file("Test.xml");

    return 0;
}
```

How to solve this problem please ?

**Edit (Output):**

Here is the actual result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
    <Week From="08/10" To="12/10" />
    <Week From="15/10" To="19/10" />
</Root>
```

And here is the desired result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root>
   <Week From="08/10" To="12/10">
       <Activity Type="0" />
   </Week>
   <Week From="15/10" To="19/10" />
</Root>
```

Comment: It'd make it clearer if you showed a small xml document and the expected result too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo question updated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sorting function removes and reinserts nodes so `_weekNode` seems to not be a reference to the latest inserted weeknode after sorting.

I suggest calling `fillWeek()` *before* sorting:

```cpp
fillWeek();
sort();
```

If you want to do the sorting before calling `fillWeek()` you need to find the node you want to fill first.

```cpp
void fillWeek()
{
    // _weekNode will now reference the first of the sorted nodes:
    _weekNode = _rootNode.first_child();
    auto activity = _weekNode.append_child("Activity");
    activity.append_attribute("Type").set_value("0");
}
```

You could also use

```cpp
template<typename Predicate>
xml_node pugi::xml_node::find_node(Predicate pred) const
```

to find an arbitrary node.

---

If you instead *move* the nodes around in your `sort()` function, your `_weekNode` will keep the reference to the last week node you appended and you will not have to find it again:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

void sort() {
    std::vector<pugi::xml_node> nodesToSort(
        std::move_iterator(_rootNode.begin()),
        std::move_iterator(_rootNode.end()));

    std::sort(nodesToSort.begin(), nodesToSort.end(), compareNodesByAttribute);

    for(pugi::xml_node node : nodesToSort) {
        _rootNode.append_move(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to sort before filing the nodes, the sort() function restrict all the actions on the other nodes, is there any other solution to keep the reference for the latest inserted week node ?

Comment: @BoHalim You need to find the new node first. I added an example for doing that.

Comment: thank you again, your solution work but it's limited, you see that it only imply that the node your work with should be the first one, and that won't be the case with a big xml file

Comment: @BoHalim  That was just one example to fit the question.  To lookup any other node, you can use `find_node`. I added that too. You could also iterate using `begin()` and `end()` to do your own finding function if needed.

Comment: @BoHalim I think I found the best way forward. See the `sort()` function I suggest in the updated answer.

Comment: That's a genius one, Thank you !

Comment: @BoHalim :-) Great that it worked out! Cheers!